# Who are these Vedic goddesses mentioned as spouses of Devas?

Tags: rig-veda, goddess, devi, vedic-gods

**[Rig Veda Book 1 Hymn 22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01022.htm)** enumerates many goddesses as the souses of the gods:

> 9 O Agni, hither bring to us the **willing Spouses of the Gods**,
>   And Tvaṣṭar, to the Soma draught.
>   10 Most youthful Agni, hither bring their Spouses, **Hotrā, Bhāratī,
>   Varūtrī, Dhiṣaṇā,** for aid.
>   11 Spouses of Heroes, Goddesses, with whole wings may they come to us
>   With great protection and with aid.
>   12 **Indrāṇī, Varuṇānī, and Agnāyī** hither I invite,
>   For weal, to drink the Soma juice.
>   13 May Heaven and Earth, the Mighty Pair, bedew for us our sacrifice,
>   And feed us full with nourishments.

The latter three are easily understandable but what about the first four? Bharati I think is the consort of Vayu but I am not sure about the others. **Are these goddesses HotrA, VarUtri & DhisanA described in any other scriptures?**

Answer (score 2):

[**Dhisana**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhisana):

> Dhisana is one of the Hindu goddess of prosperity in Hinduism. She
>   appears sometimes in the hymns in most of the mandala in Rig Veda one
>   of the vedas. She had also been mentioned as the goddess of fire, sun,
>   moon & stars.

Citing from Yajur Veda (PRAPATHAKA IV):

[i. 4. 1.](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv01.htm)

> c Ye Dhisanas, that are strong, be strengthened; gather strength, and
>   give me strength; let me not harm you, harm me not.

i. 6. 12

> That to which Dhisana impelled me have I produced; I shall praise
>   Indra before the decisive day;

i. 3. 13.

> Let Agni (kindled) with the kindling-stick hear my appeal, Let the
>   waters hear, and the divine Dhisanas; Hearken, ye pressing stones, to
>   the sacrifice of me the wise one, Let the god Savitr hearken to my
>   appeal.

**Hotrâ**

[Hotrâ](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe46/sbe46165.htm) literally means offering, as in Agni-hotra which is the sacrificial fire, which means offerings to the Agni.

> [Bhâratî](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe46/sbe46051.htm#an_2:1:11:1) the full name is given, Hotrâ Bhâratî, i. e. 'the Offering of
>   the Bharatas.'
>
> hótrâ, oblation, I, 36, 7; II, 2, 8;—Hótrâ Bháratî, I, 142, 92; II, 1,
>   11:1;—the Hotri's work, worship, IV, 2, 10:1.

Read the following [stanza](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe46/sbe46051.htm#an_2:1:11:1) for it's meaning & usage:

> 1. Thou, Agni, O god, art Aditi to the worshipper. Thou, being Hotrâ Bhâratî 1, growest strong by prayer. Thou art Idâ, living a hundred
>      winters, for (the increase of) ability. Thou, the killer of Vritra, O
>      Lord of wealth, art Sarasvatî 2.

**varūtrī**

varūtrī basically means - female protector or guardian goddess as explained here in [Sanskrit](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) dictionary

Rig Veda Book 5 [Hymn 41](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv05041.htm)

> pade-pade me jarimā ni dhāyi varūtrī vā śakrā yā pāyubhiś ca |

HYMN XLI. [Viśvedevas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05041.htm)

> Duly to each one hath my laud been offered. Strong be Varūtrī with her
>   powers to succour. May the great Mother Rasā here befriend us,
>   straight-handed, with the princes, striving forward.

HYMN XXXVIII. [Savitar](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07038.htm).

> They who come emulous to our oblation, dispensing bounty, from the
>   earth and heaven. May they and Ahibudhnya hear our calling: guard us
>   Varūtrī with the Ekadhenus.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but these are explanations of the terms not really the stories of these women. I want to know who they are as spouses of gods and also of which gods respectively?